# Flawed proof that real numbers are countable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logic, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I know there is something wrong with this argument, I am just not sure where.

Consider constructing the real numbers are equivalence classes of cauchy sequences of rationals. So in some sense the real numbers are a subset of equivalence classes of cauchy sequences of rationals so lets just consider those. In fact lets just consider all sequences of rationals.

A sequence of rationals has countably infinite many terms. Each term has countably infinite possibilities (any rational numbers). So the number of sequences is really just the same amount as

$$\bigotimes_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Q} $$
which would be countable.

Where is the flaw here?

Comment: The direct sum contains only the almost null sequences: sequences with at most finitely many entries different from $0$.  It doesn't even contain the constant  sequence $(1,1,1,\ldots)$. What you want is the direct product, and the direct product is not obviously countable (in fact, it is not countable).

Comment: Not even the binary sequences $B := \lbrace (s_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: s_n \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace ~\forall n\rbrace$ form a countable set. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Comment: Now you are saying the tensor product? If you mean $\prod \mathbb{Q}$, then the assertion that it would be countable is... problematic; in fact, it is false.

Comment: $\oplus$ (`\oplus`): direct sum. Almost null tuples. $\otimes$ (`\otimes`): [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_products_of_modules_over_a_ring) (a relatively complicated structure, not what you want here). $\prod$ (`\prod`): direct product, the set of all tuples. The latter is what you want.

Comment: You know that *finite* cross product of countable sets is countable. But there is no reason to believe an *infinite* cross product of countable sets is. Although $\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb Q$ is countable, $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb Q$ is not.

Answer (score 4):

While the **union** of countably many countable sets is countable and the product of **finitely many** countable sets is countable, the **product of countably many** countable sets is **not** countable (unless all but finitely many of those sets are singletons, *or* at least one of those sets is empty).

So you are right that $$\mathbb{R}\equiv\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Q}$$ ("$\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$" would also be appropriate notation here, but the symbol "$\otimes$" refers to something quite different). However, your error is that this does **not** imply that $\mathbb{R}$ is countable.

---

As a quick aside:

Let's say we have a set $X$ with some distinguished element $x_0$. We can consider the **subset** of $X^\mathbb{N}$ consisting of all sequences of elements of $X$ which are "mostly $x_0$," that is, such that all but finitely many elements of the sequence are $x_0$. This describes a countable set, and is basically analogous to how the countable set of reals with *terminating (= eventually $0$) decimal expansions* sits inside the uncountable set $\mathbb{R}$.

This sort of operation comes up a lot in abstract algebra; the relevant term is "direct sum" (as opposed to product), and this is denoted by "$\bigoplus$."

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/500849

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ... Oh dear lord. Fixed!

Comment: I guess it could also be that one of them is empty... ;-)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin aaaaaaAAAAAaaaargh